# LINQ Casting issue

Tags: c#, linq

I have a winform with two checkboxes and a button. On the CheckedChanged event of both checkboxes i had given the following code.

```
//Enable the button if any of the checkbox is checked
var ChkBoxes = from CheckBox ctrl in this.Controls 
               where ctrl is CheckBox select ctrl;
button1.Enabled = ChkBoxes.Any(c => ((CheckBox)c).Checked);
```

but when checking either of the checkboxes I am getting an error "**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'.**" the error comes up while executing the second line of code.

Later I updated the code to the following, which works fine. The only change I made is modified ***ctrl*** type from **CheckBox** to **Control**.

```
var ChkBoxes = from Control ctrl in this.Controls 
               where ctrl is CheckBox select ctrl;
button1.Enabled = ChkBoxes.Any(c => ((CheckBox)c).Checked);
```

My question is, in both cases I am returning controls only of type checkbox, then how come the cast error comes up. Can anyone explain me how this works?

Comment: Basically, this all comes down to the same reason you can do `foreach (string s in this.Controls)`, `foreach (int i in this.Controls)`, etc. (try it if you don't believe me): since `Controls` is not generic, the C# compiler will insert a cast for you, to be performed at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it gets converted to something like this:

```
IEnumerable<CheckBox> ChkBoxes = this.Controls.Cast<CheckBox>().Where(ctrl => ctrl is CheckBox).Select(o => o);
```

Note that the cast to `CheckBox` gets executed before the check that ensures it's valid *(the error occurs on the last line due to [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx))*.

To fix this, specify `Control` rather than `CheckBox` as you mentioned, or, even more succinctly, use [`OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var ChkBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

Comment: The first proposed fix will not work.  A type _must_ be given since the underlying collection is not strongly typed.  It would need at a minimum: `from object ctrl in this.Controls...`.

Comment: @Jeff:  You're right, I forgot `Controls` isn't generic.  I'll remove that bit...

Comment: Just FYI, LINQ-to-Objects returns `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: when I removed the Control keyword in front of ctrl, its showing an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'where'". I am using VS.NET 2008 and had reffered System.Data.Linq assembly

Comment: Thanks Jeff, after adding the object in front of the ctrl it works.

Comment: If this is to be the accepted answer, it should be correct with the right syntax at the very least.  The original query becomes something more like this:  `IEnumerable<CheckBox> ChkBoxes = this.Controls.Cast<CheckBox>().Where(ctrl => ctrl is CheckBox);`.

Comment: It's all in the spirit of having high quality answers.  Nothing personal.  ;)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using:

```
var ChkBoxes = from CheckBox ctrl in this.Controls where ctrl is CheckBox select ctrl;
```

Try using [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to do your filtering:

```
var chkBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
button1.Enabled = chkBoxes.Any(c => c.Checked); // No cast required now
```

Comment: Yes I did use the statement you had provided, which perfectly works fine. I was experimenting with the code I had mentioned, which I got perplexed on seeing the error. Thanks for the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'this.Controls' holds Controls, all of them, on the form.  The where clause has not yet been applied.

So before Linq can work with your where clause, it tried to cast the object to the type you specified, which was originally CheckBox.  When it got to a Button, the cast failed.

In your fix, you correctly used the Control type, which is valid since all objects in 'this.Controls' are Control, and then Linq can apply the rest of the Linq statement.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the exception isnt thrown because a Linq query uses what's called "Deffered" or "Lazy" evaluation.

It only started getting values for you when the second line was run, called "Enumerating" the query.

Edit - The OfType extension method from the other answer is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `Controls` collection is an `IEnumerable` which holds Controls of different types not necessarily a `CheckBox`.

You need to cast to some common base type of these controls (`Control`) then filter the collection to `CheckBox` objects.

```
var query = from Control ctrl in this.Controls
            where ctrl is CheckBox
            select (CheckBox)ctrl; // cast to CheckBox here instead

// which is equivalent to:
var q = this.Controls
            .Cast<Control>()
            .Where(ctrl => ctrl is CheckBox)
            .Select(ctrl => (CheckBox)ctrl);
```

Or filter it directly using the `OfType<T>()` extension method.  The result is a strongly typed enumerable `IEnumerable<CheckBox>`.  I would recommend this approach.

```
var query = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

Comment: After much hesitation, I decided to post my answer. None of the answers so far were very complete without fault IMHO.  It should be done right.